# C# BulkWriteAsync, Transactions and Results

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am relatively new to working with mongodb. Currently I am getting a little more familiar with the API and especially with C# drivers. I have a few understanding questions around bulk updates. As the C# driver offers a BulkWriteAsync method, I could read a lot about it in the mongo documentation. As I understand, it is possible to configure the BulkWrite not to stop in case of an error at any step. This can be done by use the unordered setting. What I did not found is, what happens to the data. Does the database do a rollback in case of an error? Or do I have to use a surrounding by myself? In case of an error: can I get details of which step was not successful? Think of a bulk with updates on 100 documents. Can I find out, which updates were not successfull? As the BulkWriteResult offers very little information, I am not sure if this operation is realy a good one for me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that `BulkWriteResult` doesn't provide the full set of information to make a call on what to do.

In the case of a `MongoBulkWriteException<T>`, however, you can access the `WriteErrors` property to get the indexes of models that errored. Here's a pared down example of how to use the property.

```
var models = sourceOfModels.ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < MaxTries; i++)
    try
    {
        return await someCollection.BulkWriteAsync(models, new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false });
    }
    catch (MongoBulkWriteException e)
    {
        // reconstitute the list of models to try from the set of failed models
        models = e.WriteErrors.Select(x => models[x.Index]).ToArray();
    }
```

Note: The above is *very* naive code. My actual code is more sophisticated. What the above does is try over and over to do the write, in each case, with only the outstanding writes. Say you started with 1000 `ReplaceOne<T>` models to write, and 900 went through; the second try will try against the remaining 100, and so on until retries are exhausted, or there are no errors.

If the code is not within a transaction, and an error occurs, of course nothing is rolled back; you have some writes that succeed and some that do not. In the case of a transaction, [the exception is still raised](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#error-handling-inside-transactions) (MongoDB 4.2+). Prior to that, you would not get an exception.

Finally, while the default is ordered writes, unordered writes can be very useful when the writes are unrelated to one another (e.g. documents representing DDD aggregates where there are no dependencies). It's this same "unrelatedness" that also obviates the need for a transaction.